# Update a column with Javascript and JsonResult in Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my table, and I want to add a column to the right where a user will be able to enter a value and save. (It needs to save the value to a sql table)

Code in my View:

```
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var items in Model.tbl_Stuff)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@items.ID</td>
                        <td>@items.Description</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtAmount" /></td>              
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

This is the Javascript: In the function is where I should be able to update each row, how do I loop though a table row, and update the inserted value on the new column to the sql table via the controller action?
EDIT: this is my edited script according to the suggestion below, it sends the value to controller.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">    

$("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {        
    var stuffarray= new Array();
    var txtEmployeeBidAmount = $("#txtEmployeeBidAmount");
    $("#tblStuff TBODY TR").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var stuf= {};
        stuf.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
        stuffarray.push(stuf);
    });

    //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("UpdateStuff","Home")",
        data: JSON.stringify(stuffarray),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r + " record(s) saved.");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a table, you require to loop the table using the following sample to get text box value from each row:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>Computer</td>
            <td>3434</td>
            <td><input type='text' class='val' value='100' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>Stationary</td>
            <td>111</td>
             <td><input type='text' class='val' value='200' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>Stationary</td>
            <td>11</td>
             <td><input type='text' class='val' value='400' /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var table = $("table tbody");

table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        Id = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        Product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();
        Val = $tds.find('.val').val();
    
    alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nId: ' + Id
          + '\nProduct: ' + Product
          + '\nQuantity: ' + Quantity
          + '\nVal: ' + Val);
});
```

Finally add them to an `JavaScript` array object to update in the controller.

Here's a sample in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72ycto0g)

Comment: thanks @AT-2017 . I've edited my question to reflect your answer. I get the results.